# How to use a magnet and a solenoid to create a "normally off" magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism

I've tried searching for an answer, but don't really know what to ask for so have had no luck.

Are there such as things as 'reverse' electromagnets - i.e. a permanent magnet surrounded by a coil which, when energized, neutralizes the magnetism?

I'm trying to design a device which will stay put in the event of a power cut.

That means a magnet that is "off" when powered, but as the power gets lost, it turns "on".

Comment: Your idea is feasible. It is quite possible to neutralize one magnetic field with another so that if one disappears the other remains. For example, this way the action of reed switches can be reversed (from normally open to normally closed).

Comment: @DavidShaw This will be a better question if you edit it to include the information about the size of the permanent magnet you're using, perhaps a link to its datasheet or product page, what is the intended application, etc. All of that will be important in figuring out an answer. As it stands, your question is very broad and the only possible answer is "yeah, it's possible, what else do you want to know". It's this "what else do you want to know" bit that turns it into a good question :)